# wrapping text in table

Tags: tables

For some reason, the text in my table is not wrapping up and I keep getting the error: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.. can anyone help with making a simple table with wrapping the text: below is the MWE:

```
   %---------------------Preamble---------------%
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,9.5pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[total={13cm,19.5cm},top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm, includefoot]{geometry} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{microtype}          % removes extra spacing between text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % fancy heading style in headers and footers
\usepackage{graphicx}           % include graphs/ figures  in the file
\usepackage{array,threeparttable}       % to add footnotes to the tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}    % to create some space between table caption and table, otherwise there was no space
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,skip=0pt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}              % figures as 6 (a), 6 (b) etc.
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tikz}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[ht]
  \scriptsize
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
    \toprule
          & \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{Starting} & \textbf{treatments} & \textbf{processes} & \textbf{Average} & \textbf{error (\%)} \\
    \midrule
    R2    & 0.3  & 0.6  & 0.5  & 0.7  & 0.3  & 8 \\
    C     & 2   & 17   & 2   & 5   & 2   & 8 \\
    k     & 6    & 0     & 2    & 226   & 9    & 1 \\
    Efficiency of testing system* & 74    & 9    & 8    & 5    & 8    & 0 \\
    St.dev. ** & 1    & 1    & 1    & 1    & 2    & - \\    
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:first-modeldata}%
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
```

Comment: You only specified 6 columns but you are wanting 7 columns.  Add one more p{1cm} to the table definition.

Comment: @R.Schumacher  How can I add vertical line after the first column. I am trying to do {p|{1cm}}, but this does not work

Comment: @R.Schumacher   Also the headers are not aligned with the numbers. can you please help?

Comment: You really do not want to use vertical rules if you are using `booktabs` to format the table. See the documentation for the package. That recommends not using them. If you must use them for some reason, don't use the `booktabs` commands for this table, at least. (But best not to use them.)

Comment: You've asked for paragraph alignment so the contents of the cells will be aligned on the left. It isn't clear what you want aligned with what.

Comment: @cfr  I basically want to wrap the text. And, I do need vertical lines for the first column at least. The alignment can be centre or left.. but I do not know if I can still wrap the text then. Therefore, I tried "P" align

Comment: The text is wrapped. If you must use vertical lines, fine. But don't use the `booktabs` stuff in that case. There is no such option as `9.5pt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version with `siunitx` to align the numbers and `booktabs` rules:

[image: pretty table]

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,openright]{book}
\usepackage[total={13cm,19.5cm},top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{array,threeparttable,siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,skip=0pt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \scriptsize
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Add caption}
      \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}*{6}{S}}
        \toprule
        & \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{Starting} & \textbf{treatments} & \textbf{processes} & \textbf{Average} & \textbf{error (\%)} \\\midrule
        R2    & 0.3  & 0.6  & 0.5  & 0.7  & 0.3  & 8 \\
        C     & 2   & 17   & 2   & 5   & 2   & 8 \\
        k     & 6    & 0     & 2    & 226   & 9    & 1 \\
        Efficiency of testing system* & 74    & 9    & 8    & 5    & 8    & 0 \\
        St.dev.** & 1    & 1    & 1    & 1    & 2    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{--} \\\bottomrule
      \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:first-modeldata}%
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you really need vertical rules:

```
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \scriptsize
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Add caption}
      \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}|*{6}{S}}
        \hline
        & \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{Starting} & \textbf{treatments} & \textbf{processes} & \textbf{Average} & \textbf{error (\%)} \\\hline
        R2    & 0.3  & 0.6  & 0.5  & 0.7  & 0.3  & 8 \\
        C     & 2   & 17   & 2   & 5   & 2   & 8 \\
        k     & 6    & 0     & 2    & 226   & 9    & 1 \\
        Efficiency of testing system* & 74    & 9    & 8    & 5    & 8    & 0 \\
        St.dev.** & 1    & 1    & 1    & 1    & 2    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{--} \\\hline
      \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:first-modeldata}%
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
```

But the result is (predictably) much uglier:

[image: ugly table]

`booktabs` tables really do look nicer.